# Get domain dns name and domain flat name

Tags: active-directory

I want to know the domain DNS name and domain flat name of a domain. I just know the IPAddress of the domain controller. How do I fetch domain DNS name and domain flat name using IPAddress of a domain controller. For eg. 172.18.2.111 is the domain controller IPAddress and assume it is under domain 'example.com' whose domain DNS name is 'example.com' and domain flat name is 'example'.With the help of IPAddress how do I get those names? Is it possible (using native code or java code)? How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `dsrolegetprimarydomaininformation` api:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/dsrolegetprimarydomaininformation.html

Other easier ways would depend on the language.

Comment: Can u provide me an example of how to use it ?

Comment: The above function works for current running system. If I have to provide a specific IPAddress like "172.18.2.111", It returns Access Denied